# UWP ListView Selected Items just returns some items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, uwp

I am doing an UWP app and I am using a `ListView` to display a list of items. I am using an `ObservableCollection` for that. The `ListView` uses multiple selection mode but when I check which items have been selected it just returns half of the selected items. Here is my code for the

**XAML file**

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Travel.Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="45" Width="145" FontSize="30"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="20,0,0,10" />
            <TextBlock Text="Select the items you want to add to the travel:" FontSize="15"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="20,0,0,10"/>
            <ListView x:Name="ItemsList" Margin="20, 10, 20, 20" IsItemClickEnabled="True" x:DefaultBindMode="OneWay" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Item">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" FontSize="15" Text="{x:Bind Name}" Margin="0,0,30,0" ></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Button x:Name="AddItems" Content="Add Items" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="AddItems_Click" Margin="20, 10, 0, 0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsOfTravel { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

private void AddItems_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(var item in ItemsList.SelectedItems)
            {
                ItemsOfTravel.Remove((Item)item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear how `ItemsList.SelectedItems` won't return all the items you've selected, have you tried debugging to check the value of `SelectedItems` when the event handler `AddItems_Click` is called? And if so, what was the result? Can you provide some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to get an array out of the selected items like this:

```
private void AddItems_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            

            foreach(Item item in ItemsList.SelectedItems.ToArray())
            {                
                ItemsOfTravel.Remove(item);
            }            
        }
```

It seems that the selected items result was changing each time I removed an item from the Observable collection and that's is why it didn't iterate through all the items

Comment: It is telling me I have to wait for that 2 days